# Access VBA able to detect form's filter settings?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there a way to determine what filter settings a user has selected in order to translate them into SQL?

I have a form in continuous form view that a user can switch to data sheet view, set filters on any of the columns, then flip back to the continuous form view to see the results. I have a companion report with the same format as the continuous form and want to filter it by passing it the criteria in SQL.

I am thinking I can use the recordset clone property to identify the records based on key value, but wondered if there was a way to detect what the user actually filtered on?

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is fairly easy. The form's `Filter`-Property contains the filter expression. You should be able to use it directly in the where-condition of the report.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize any filtering set by the user triggers an update to the form's filter property. (Which makes sense)

Comment: The `Filter` might contain a value but if `FilterOn` is False, it is not applied